# I've already installed binutils in osx 10.11, but objdump still doesn't work

Tags: homebrew, osx-elcapitan, binutils

I've tried hard to install binutil with HomeBrew onto osx 10.11, finally succeed, but objdump still doesn't work. The response given by terminal is as follow:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ Mars$ brew install binutils
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/binutils-2.26.el_capitan.bo
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/binutils-2.26.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring binutils-2.26.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/binutils/2.26: 109 files, 140.3M
MacBook-Pro:~ Mars$ objdump
-bash: objdump: command not found
```

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 14):

To avoid conflicts with the utilities distributed by Apple, the binutils executables installed by Homebrew all have "g" prefixed to their names (so, for instance, `objdump` becomes `gobjdump`).

Answer (score 1):

you need to update your `$PATH` to include the homebrew install location.  you probably want to look at other places people have asked this question like:

https://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are